# ¿Conectar una aplicación de Java a un servidor hosting (Bluehost)?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-8.2

Estoy tratando de conectar una aplicación hecha en Java a una base de datos de un servidor hosting (**BLUEHOST**), pero hasta el momento no lo he logrado ya que no me permite la conexión.

El servidor de base de datos es **MySQL**.

mi código de conexión :

```html
package sistema.gestion.logistica.db;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Conexion {
 
    private final String base = "dbApplication";
    private final String user = "usuarioDB";
    private final String password = "passApplication";
    private final String url = "jdbc:mysql://184.6.118.32:3306/" + base;
    private Connection con = null;

    public Connection getConexion() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.user, this.password);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conectado");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error de conexion");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return con;
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿y te puedes conectar con una herramienta externa, mysql query browser por ejemplo? para corroborar que sí tienes acceso a la base

Comment: gracias por responder pero ya logre conectarme muy amable por la respuesta.

Comment: modificaste algo para poder conectarte ?

Comment: tengo el mismo problema,necesito conectarme a un servidor con la direccion 10.0.0.2, esta linea me quedaria asi ?
private final String url = "jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.2:3306/" + base;